# perl multipart request using REST::Client

Tags: perl, multipartform-data

I am using Perl's REST::Client to make a multipart POST request:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use REST::Client;
use JSON;

$file = 'output.csv';
$headers = {'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token.''}; 
$client = REST::Client->new(); 
$req = '{"sessionId" => '.$sessionId.' , "content" => ["file" => ['.$file.']]}';
$client->setHost(<host>); 

$client->POST( '/api/test',$req, $headers);
$response = from_json($client->responseContent());
```

REST api is as follow:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
@Timed
public Response<Map<String, Object>> test(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("sessionId") Long sessionId,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
}
```

when I run the script getting following error:

> Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found]

I am new with perl, is anything wrong with syntax or something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[REST::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client) expects you to make the entire message body, and you aren't doing that. Indeed, you shouldn't be trying to do manually construct the request (or even the JSON). I suspect from your code that you aren't really supposed to make a multipart request, but I'd have to see the API docs to say anything about that.

Here's the similar task in [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent). Instead of trying to make the message body, I make the request with a data structure that Mojo figures out:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use v5.10;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $url ='http://httpbin.org/post';
my $session_id = 'deadbeef';
my $filename = 'upload_file.csv';

my $tx = $ua->post(
    $url,
    form => {
        session => $session_id,
        some_file => {
            file => $filename,
            },
        },
);


say "Request:\n", $tx->req->to_string;

say "Response:\n", $tx->result->to_string;
```

Sending this to [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/) is a convenient way to test things. The output shows that the header and multipart stuff happens for you automatically:

```
Request:
POST /post HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)
Content-Length: 208
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=75OiX
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: httpbin.org

--75OiX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="session"

deadbeef
--75OiX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="some_file"; filename="upload_file.csv"

upload,this,file
here's,another,line

--75OiX--

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 03:44:04 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 516
Content-Type: application/json
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0

{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {
    "some_file": "upload,this,file\nhere's,another,line\n"
  },
  "form": {
    "session": "deadbeef"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Content-Length": "208",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=75OiX",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Mojolicious (Perl)",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5ea3b204-12cfdb84b9c9c504da559e80"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "199.170.132.3",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

I have many more examples in [Mojolicious Web Clients](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients).

Comment: I need to pass the token in header, so how can I add header with above solutions ?

Comment: You can easily add headers with a hash reference after the URL. In the [Mojo::UserAgent](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) docs, there's an example with the `Accept` header. And, I have lots of examples in [Mojo Web Clients](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients). You can also ask another question about that.